# How hard is it to setup SQL Replication? Can it be done by a Semi SQL User?

Tags: sql, replication

I'm a semi SQL user, not a DBA, just a regular programmer. One of my upcoming jobs require a SQL replication configuration. I have never done such configuration before

My colleagues have been advicing me to hire an SQL Consultant or DBA to do this.

I was also thinking that maybe I can just do this myself. There's lots of information in google on how to do this.

Any advice? Is this something that a semi SQL user shouldn't be doing? How complex is it to setup SQL replication?

Thanks for the advice

Comment: Merge? Transactional? Snapshot? What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: ...what's a "semi SQL user", BTW?!?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at the Replication topics covered in BOL on MSDN Library.

The first thing you'll need to do is determine if you require one-way or two-way synchronization - and which type of replication will suit your needs.  From here you'll want to setup a test environment to familiarize yourself with the details, this is crucial.

If you have any questions feel free to post them to the [SQL Server Replication Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/threads).